# Query don´t work in php

Tags: php, oracle

Hi i have a query to oracle bd, which show routes and stops, when i ran in the developer oracle work like charm but when copy the query in my php file don't show anything.

i think that the problem is the syntax but i don't know where, the variables $bus, $fecha and $ruta work well

this is the query

```
SELECT * FROM  (
SELECT DISTINCT B.BUSNUMBER,
                OP.Stopid,
                OP.GPSX,
                OP.GPSY,
                L.SHORTNAME,
                OP.TELEGRAMDATE
  FROM Sgco.OPERATIONALINFO OP, sgco.LINES L, sgco.BUSES B
  WHERE  L.PLANVERSIONID =
              (SELECT MAX (p.planversionid)
                 FROM sgco.planversions p
                WHERE     PLANVERSIONID NOT IN ('9001', '9000')
                      AND p.activationdate <=
                             (SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/YYYY')
                                FROM DUAL)
                      AND B.PLANVERSIONID = L.PLANVERSIONID) 
       AND L.LINEID = OP.LINEID
       AND OP.LINEID =
              (SELECT lineid
                 FROM sgco.lines
                WHERE     shortname = UPPER ('$ruta')
                      AND planversionid = L.PLANVERSIONID)      
       AND B.BUSID = OP.BUSNUMBER

UNION ALL

SELECT  DISTINCT B.BUSNUMBER,
               OP.Stopid,
               OP.GPSX,
               OP.GPSY,
               L.SHORTNAME,
               OP.TELEGRAMDATE
  FROM Sgco.OPERATIONALINFO OP, sgco.LINES L, sgco.BUSES B
  WHERE     B.PLANVERSIONID =
              (SELECT MAX (p.planversionid)
                 FROM sgco.planversions p
                WHERE     PLANVERSIONID NOT IN ('9001', '9000')
                      AND p.activationdate <=
                             (SELECT TO_CHAR ('$fecha')
                                FROM DUAL)
                      AND L.PLANVERSIONID = B.PLANVERSIONID)
       AND B.BUSID = OP.BUSNUMBER
       AND OP.BUSNUMBER =
              (SELECT BUSID
                 FROM SGCO.BUSES
                WHERE BUSNUMBER = '$bus' 
                AND planversionid = B.PLANVERSIONID)
       AND L.LINEID = OP.LINEID
) x

WHERE  TELEGRAMDATE = (SELECT MAX(TELEGRAMDATE) FROM OPERATIONALINFO)
```

Part of the php

```
<form action="<?php  htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
Ruta:<input type="text" name="ruta"><br>
<input name="bus" type="submit" ><br>
bus:<input type="text" name="bus"><br>
<input name="ruta" type="submit" ><br>
</form> 



<script>


                    <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    if(isset( $_POST["ruta"])) {

    }
    if(isset( $_POST["bus"])) {

    }


$ruta = $_POST["ruta"];
$bus = $_POST["bus"];
$fecha = date("d/m/Y");
$db ="---line of conection--";
$connect = oci_connect(--user pass--, $db);



$query = "--The query--";

$result = oci_parse($connect, $query);
 oci_execute($result);
  // Now iterate over all placemarks (rows)


$i=0;
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)) != false)
 {


echo $datosq [$i][0]=$row[0];//stoid
```

**Update**

show this whit error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

```
<b>Warning</b>:  oci_execute() [<a href='function.oci-execute'>function.oci-execute</a>]: ORA-01843: not a valid month in <b>/var/www/html/busestr/pruebabuses.php</b> on line <b>108</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  oci_fetch_array() [<a href='function.oci-fetch-array'>function.oci-fetch-array</a>]: ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in <b>/var/www/html/busestr/pruebabuses.php</b> on line <b>113</b><br />
```

Comment: *"Query don´t work in php"* so show us the PHP.

Comment: so is this `msyql` or `oracle`? Why did you tag `mysql`, when you state this is for `oracle`?

Comment: is a BD in oracle @Sean

Comment: The php is easy the problem is the query don't show results when run in php @fred-ii-

Comment: well if the query works outside of the php but not inside of the php - perhaps, just perhaps it is the php at issue?

Comment: I put part of the php, but insist that not is the problem

Comment: Shouldn't there be some `oci_bind_by_name` calls in there to bind the PHP vars to the parameter names in the query?

Comment: If you are so sure the php is not at fault, have you tried  `echo $query;` and then run that again in your database directly ?

Comment: @b.enoit.be, no echo query print the code but no the result, i try echo result but nothing happend

Comment: why was this tagged as `mysql` and `oracle`? those don't use the same API.

Comment: sorry @Fred-ii- i ready remove the tag

Comment: I don't see where `$bus, $fecha` and `$ruta` are being defined. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- is a part of the php, the variables are being defined like i said before 
$ruta = $_POST["ruta"];
$bus = $_POST["bus"];
$fecha = date("d/m/Y");

Comment: well, add error reporting as I said. Plus, if your form doesn't specifically imply a POST method, forms default to a GET method, in turn and potentially failing silently and error reporting won't do much good but is worth a shot. Make sure that all elements bear the name attributes with no typos, lettercase etc. hard to solve this without seeing all the parts.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is propably in comparing date and text values. `p.activationdate` is DATE type, right?
Expression

```
p.activationdate <= (SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/YYYY')
                            FROM DUAL)
```

then causes implicit conversion between CHAR and DATE. You can't rely on implicit date format.
Better is to compare dates directly

```
p.activationdate <= SYSDATE
```

Expression

```
p.activationdate <= (SELECT TO_CHAR ('$fecha')
                            FROM DUAL)
```

is strange. What is result of '$fetcha'? What is its type and value? There is not data format provided, to_char uses default format. Again - you can't rely on it. If $fecha = date('d/m/Y'), use

```
p.activationdate <= TO_DATE ('$fecha','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Comment: $fecha = date("d/m/Y") provided by php

Comment: Ok, I added an edit in the end, which should work

Comment: Don't help i make the change but stilll no results